# div max-height set dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

I have a web app using master page and content pages (see the attached image). I need to set max-width of one div in content page dynamically accordint to the browser window size (so that the whole app stays on the page, without scrolling). I couldn't find the sloution (or couldn't replicate the results) using just html and CSS. So I'm thinking to do it using javascript. But the problem is, I NEVER used it, so I really have no clue how to do it. I'd really appriciate if someone took a couple of minutes and write the function that will do it. As I see it, I should take difference in height between bottom edge of the header and top edge of the footer and subtract height values of searchbar and button bar.

[image]

EDIT:
Thanks to maxedison for providing that code. But, how do I use it? :D I'm a total noob. I have a problem, since I use masterpage and content pages. Where do I put that code?

**EDIT 2 - THE ANSWER:**

I looked a little further into how to use jQuery, and searched here some more, and I found a solution. Next time I start developing an application, I'll use jQuery from the bottoms up...It just simplifies some things so much. :)

So for the solution: It's similar to what maxedison suggested, but I changed it so, that I set height with CSS and I just added a fixed value to deduct from window.height.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        $('.myStyle').css({ 'height': (($(window).height()) - 350) + 'px' });

        $(window).resize(function () {
            $('.myStyle').css({ 'height': (($(window).height()) - 350) + 'px' });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @MrLister - I'm not sure this is possible in CSS. I've also sought a pure-CSS solution to make a div expand to fit the available vertical height, but without success.

Comment: @Mr Lister - I tried just about any CSS solution I could find...none did what I wanted. So I thought I'd give javascript or jQuery a go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery, it would look something like:

```
function resetHeight(){
    var newHeight = $(window).height() - $('.header').outerHeight() - $('.searchBar').outerHeight() - $('.buttons').outerHeight() - $('.footer').outerHeight();
    $('.content').height(newHeight);
}

$(function(){
    newHeight();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        resetHeight();
    });
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Now just to learn, where I should put this code. :D I'll be using it first time, so fingers crossed, I can make it work. :) Should I put this in my content page or in my master page? Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention. I'm using .NET 2, because of some limitations I needed to consider. Will this work, or is it for newer versions on .net?

Comment: @user1080533 .NET version has nothing to do with jQuery (which is javascript) since it is client side. You should put this code in your `<head>` tag, in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: @Nate Thanks, I did google it and read some tutorials for jQuery and I managed to get what I wanted. I updated my question with an answer. :)